# Getting exception when downloading large file

Tags: windows-phone-8, out-of-memory

I am developing an audio/video related application where user need to download video to play it locally, for this i am using this code-

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient wb = new WebClient();


        wb.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("Video url", UriKind.Absolute)); 
        wb.DownloadProgressChanged += wbchange;
    }
    private void wbchange(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
          progressBar2.Value = e.BytesReceived;
          progressBar2.Maximum = e.TotalBytesToReceive;   
    }
```

It is working fine for small video but showing an error for large video
The error is-`System.OutOfMemoryException: Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program.
   at MS.Internal.FrameworkCallbacks.NotifyManagedDebuggerOnNativeOOM()`

Please suggest me some way to get rid of this or any other way to download video for better performence?

Thanks for concern:)

Comment: How large is the video?

Comment: It is not fix since there is different kinds of video to download.

Comment: @bash.d video size may reach to 70 mb.

Comment: Maybe too much to handle? Could be a bug, too...

Comment: what can i do is there any alternative to do?

Comment: When downloaded a chunk, write it to disk, maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that case, you can use Background Transfert Service.
Already succeeded to download large files (around 50/60mo).

Works only over 3g or more.

msdn:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286419(v=vs.105).aspx
example: http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2011/11/26/31-days-of-mango-day-26-background-file-transfer/